Mudar o nome do arquivo a ser salvo no multer
Estou usando o multer para salvar fotos/pdfs que são enviados do meu front-end mas não consigo salvar o arquivo com o originalname e sua extensão, ele somente salvar com o filename.
componente do front-end
const CadastroCurso = () => {
   ...

  const handleFileChange = event => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      setFoto(file);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_aluno', idUsuario);
    formData.append('curso_id_area', selectedArea);
    formData.append('curso_id_materia', selectedMateria);
    formData.append('nome_curso', nomeCurso);
    formData.append('modalidade', modalidade);
    formData.append('anotacoes', anotacoes);
    formData.append('valor', valor);
    formData.append('curso_id_pagamento', cursoIdPagamento);
    formData.append('data_ini', dataIni);
    formData.append('data_fini', dataFini);
    formData.append('duracao', duracao);
    formData.append('media', media);
    if (foto) {
      formData.append('certificado', foto);
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${RotaBanco}/curso/adicionarCurso`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Erro ao adicionar curso');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
        ...
        <input id="imagem" name="imagem" type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
        <button type="submit">Adicionar Matéria</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CadastroCurso;


Backend
router.post('/adicionarCurso', upload.single('certificado'), (req, res) => {
  const { nome_curso, modalidade, anotacoes, valor, curso_id_area, curso_id_materia, curso_id_pagamento, data_ini, data_fini,
          duracao, media, id_aluno} = req.body;

  console.log(req.file);
  let certificado;
  if(req.file == undefined) {
    certificado = "NULL";
  } else {
    //console.log(req);
    certificado = req.file.filename; // puxando por esse nome
    // certificado = req.file.originalname;
  }

  // Verifica se todos os campos obrigatórios foram fornecidos
  if (!nome_curso || !modalidade || !valor || !curso_id_area || !curso_id_materia || !curso_id_pagamento || !data_ini|| !data_fini ||
      !media || !id_aluno) {
    res.status(400).send('Todos os campos são obrigatórios.');
    return;
  }

  const query = `SELECT adicionarCurso("${nome_curso}", "${modalidade}", "${anotacoes}", ${valor}, ${curso_id_area}, ${curso_id_materia}, ${curso_id_pagamento}, '${data_ini}', '${data_fini}', ${duracao}, ${media}, ${id_aluno}, '${certificado}') AS novo_id`;

  console.log(query);

  connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao adicionar curso:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor');
      return;
    }

    // Retorna o ID do usuário recém-cadastrado como resposta
    const novoId = results[0].novo_id;
    res.json({ novoId });
  });
});

multer
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

// Configuração do destino de armazenamento
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './Images/'); // Change the destination folder path if necessary
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let name = file.file.originalname;
    cb(null, name); // Keep the original filename
  },
});

// Configuração do multer
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = upload;


Tentei trocar as variaveis de filename, como envio do Frontend, como trato no backend como altero o nome e salvar partes

Uma maneira de solucionar o problema é renomear o arquivo a partir do ponto que já possui os dados do req.file, que no seu código é a partir do console.log(req.file)
Toda essa configuração abaixo é feita apenas no backend (servidor) [nodejs].
A solução, de maneira resumida funciona assim:

recebe um arquivo (multipart/form-data) no primeiro middleware (ali onde tem o upload.single)
a partir do segundo middleware já possuo os dados para renomear o arquivo (os dados estão no objeto req.file) são os padrões do multer
uso a lib nativa do nodejs fs para renomear o arquivo, através da função fs.renameSync
Renomeia o arquivo através do valor da variável req.file.originalname.
no servidor o arquivo estará no caminho relativo uploads/

Por exemplo: Um arquivo que tenha sido feito o upload vai possuir o nome no padrão do multer (para este passo eu não configurei o multer para nomear os arquivos. Dessa forma o arquivo que é enviado ao meu servidor (ao terminar o primeiro middleware (que é o do próprio multer), vai possuir o nome no seguinte padrão (2a39086031204b49df1b80322e9cd5ff), após isso, no segundo middleware (fileNameUploadRename) posso renomear o arquivo.
Veja um exemplo de implementação de um middleware que possui esta lógica:
const fs = require('fs');

const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/'
});
router.post('/adicionarCurso', upload.single('certificado'), (req, res) => {
    try {
        fs.access(`${req.file.destination}${req.file.originalname}`, fs.constants.COPYFILE_EXCL, (err) => {
            if (err && err.errno === -2) {
                fs.renameSync(req.file.path, `${req.file.destination}/${req.file.originalname}`);
                res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Operação realizada com sucesso' });
                return;
            }
            res.status(409).json({ msg: 'O arquivo já existe' });
            fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            err: "Houve um erro ao atualizar o certificado, tente novamente"
        })
    }
});

Para mais informações consulte a documentação do fs e valores das constantes do fs

Repare que no exemplo acima eu faço uso de algumas funções específicas da função `fs`. Por exemplo uso a constante `COPYFILE_EXCL` que fará operação de cópia falhar se o arquivo de destino já existir. Ou seja, não desejo sobre-escrever o arquivo. (O que vale é o primeiro a ser enviado), então eu recomendo que se deseja outro comportamento escolha a constante adequada para a sua situação.
